# PHP Print array values in order which is in another array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have an array ($fields_order_obj) which contains the names and orderindex of a list I want to print in a table.
In another array ($data) I have all the values I want to print, but not in the same order as in the $fields_order_obj array. I fetch this array out of SQL with a query with fetchmode ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC and I go trought each row as with foreach ($data as $row) {}

```
$fields_order_obj ([name] => Del_Month [size] => 10 [reportindex] => 0, [name] => Del_Date [size] => 10 [reportindex] => 1, [name] => Article [size] => 10 [reportindex] => 3, ect.)
$data [0]([name] => Article [value] => "A", [name] => Del_Date [value] => "03-03-21", [name] => Del_Month [value] => "March"),[1]([name] => Article [value] => "B", [name] => Del_Date [value] => "01-02-21", [name] => Del_Month [value] => "Feb"), ect.
```

What I have so far:

```
print "<table style=\"width:100%\">";
print " <tr>\n";
foreach ($fields_order_obj as $obj){
      print "<th>".$obj->name."</th>\n";
}
print " </tr>\n";
foreach ($data as $row) {
    print " <tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $name => $value) {
        print "<td>".$value."</td>\n";
    }
}
print " </tr>\n";
```

Obviously the data is not printed in the order I want, I need to check and compare the `name` of the field and then check the `reportindex` to print it in the correct order, but I don't seem to be able to write the right code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
print "<table style=\"width:100%\">";
print " <tr>\n";
foreach ($fields_order_obj as $obj){
      print "<th>".$obj->name."</th>\n";
}
print " </tr>\n";
foreach ($data as $row) {
    print " <tr>\n";
    foreach ($fields_order_obj as $obj){
        $fieldName = $obj->name;
        print "<td>".$row[$fieldName]."</td>\n";
    }
}
print " </tr>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your code should be something like this:

```php
print "<table style=\"width:100%\">";
print " <tr>\n";
foreach ($fields_order_obj as $obj){
      print "<th>".$obj->name."</th>\n";
}
print " </tr>\n";
foreach ($data as $row) {
    print " <tr>\n";
    foreach ($fields_order_obj as $obj){
        print "<td>".$row[$obj->name]."</td>\n";
    }
}
print " </tr>\n";
```

You should iterate over your fields array to keep printing in the intended order and get row data by the field name. Keep in mind that you should aware of situations if your data has no all fields specified in the `$fields_order_obj`.

Comment: It seems $row->$fieldname is empty, as it does not print anything, should there be a => in the first foreach (foreach ($data as $row =>.....)?

Comment: It was not easy to understand your data structure...

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction, Txs!